# Lipchitz vs Bounded Derivative

Tags: real-analysis

I hear many times teachers say that a function has bounded derivative when what they mean is that the functions is Lipschitz. They do that on purpose and sometimes they even say "of course i mean Lipschitz by that".

I wanted to ask if both things are really the same or if just one implication or no implications are right. Maybe is true only under certain conditions.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Lipschitz function is certainly continuous, and in fact uniformly continuous. But it needn't be differentiable.

However, by the Mean Value Theorem, if a function has bounded derivative, it is automatically Lipschitz with constant $M=\sup|f'(x)|$

Comment: @Peter_Tamaroff And if it's Lipschitz + differentiable then has bounded derivative?

Comment: @MykeArya Yes. Again, the MVT comes into play. The derivative is bounded by the Lipschitz constant, since $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|=|f'(\mu)|\leq \alpha$$

Comment: Also, I guess what your teachers are thinking about is that a Lipschitz function is almost everywhere differentiable (where “almost everywhere” has a precise mathematical meaning, but you can think of it as its literal meaning) and that this derivative is uniformly bounded by the Lipschitz constant where it exists.