# Is Lipschitz condition on derivatives essentially the same thing as epsilon-delta proof?

Tags: derivatives, epsilon-delta, lipschitz-functions, gradient-descent

I am very confused about Lipchitz gradient/derivative. It's often used in machine learning proofs about gradient descent.

Are Lipschitz and epsilon delta proof essentially the same thing?

**Lipchitz**: A function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be a Lipschitz function, provided if there is a $L>0$ such that,

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le L|x-y| \text{  for all } x,y \in D$$
**Epsilon delta proof**: For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that

$$f(x)-f(y) < \epsilon \text{ if } |x-y| < \delta$$

The two ideas are saying the same thing: if $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ differ by this much, then $x$ and $y$ differ by that much. Am I right?

A related question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364824/lipchitz-vs-bounded-derivative).

Comment: The latter is just continuity, the former is Lipschitz continuity. Lipschitz continuity is stronger.

Comment: The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof is a definition of a uniformly continuous function, which is a weaker condition than Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: Is weaker or stronger in the sense:  Lipschitz is contained in $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, or more precisely, Lipschitz implies $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a counterexample: the function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous, and in fact uniformly continuous, but it is not Lipschitz.

Lipschitz continuity means that the difference ratio 
$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}
$$
is bounded. So, it says something *very specific* about the comparison between the difference of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ versus the difference of $x$ and $y$.

One way you can see that the square root function defined above is not Lipschitz is that the limit of difference ratios
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
is equal to infinity, and so the difference ratio $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ is certainly not bounded.

The $\epsilon,\delta$ definition says nothing at all about the ratio $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$. Granted, though, it does say *something* about the difference of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ versus the difference of $x$ and $y$, but what it says is quite a bit more vague than boundedness of the difference ratio.